# Expected Value of random variables defined by uniformly random permutation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ be a uniformly random permutation of $[n] = \{0, 1, . . . , n − 1\}$. This means that for each $i \in [n]$,
$X_i  \in [n]$ and $X_i \ne X_j$ for $i \ne j$. For $1 \le i \le n − 2$, let
$Y_i  = 1$ when $X_i > X_{i-1}$ and $X_i > X_{i+1}$
and $0$ otherwise.

Let $Z = \sum_{n=1}^{n-2} Y_i$

What is $E[Z]$? What is $Cov(Y_i,Y_j)$? What is $Var(Z)$?

My thought was that the probability that $Y_i = 1$ for each $i$ is $1/4$ since the probability that $X_i > X_{i-1}$ is $1/2$ and the probability that $X_i > X_{i+1}$ is $1/2$.  This would mean that $E[Y_i]$ is also equal to $1/4$.  Finally, $E[Z]$ equals the sum of the expected values of $Y_i$ from $i = 1$ to $n-2$.  This would mean $E[Z] = \frac14 (n-1)$.  Is this the correct approach?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the summation notation as well as the not equals signs.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use mathajx for typing. I fix some formatting, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My thought was that the probability that $Y_i = 1$ for each $i$ is $1/4$ since the probability that $X_i > X_{i-1}$ is $1/2$ and the probability that $X_i > X_{i+1}$ is $1/2$

This feels wrong, because those two probabilities are not independent.

For three elements, there are $3! = 6$ permutations, and only $2$ of them are "success" (i.e., the middle element is greater than the other two). Hence $P[Y_i=1]=E[Y_i]=1/3 $

Hence $E[Z]= \frac13 (n-2)$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense now for the expectation.  Does that mean that the covariance would be E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 1/3 - (1/3)(1/3) = 2/9 ?

Comment: I don't think it's so simple. $E[XY] = P(X=1,Y=1)$ , now that depends on the distance between them. Namely $E[Y_i Y_i] = 1/3$,  $E[Y_i Y_{i+1}] = 0$  $E[Y_i Y_{i+2}] = ?$